# HTTP and Sessions

Tags: http, session, web, session-state, stateful

I just went through the specification of http 1.1 at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html and came across a section about connections http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8 that says

" A significant difference between HTTP/1.1 and earlier versions of HTTP is that persistent connections are the default behavior of any HTTP connection. That is, unless otherwise indicated, the client SHOULD assume that the server will maintain a persistent connection, even after error responses from the server.

Persistent connections provide a mechanism by which a client and a server can signal the close of a TCP connection. This signaling takes place using the Connection header field (section 14.10). Once a close has been signaled, the client MUST NOT send any more requests on that connection. "

Then I also went through a section on http state management at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965 that says in its section 2 that

"Currently, HTTP servers respond to each client request without relating that request to previous or subsequent requests;"

A section about the need to have persistent connections in the RFC 2616 also said that prior to persistent connections every time a client wished to fetch a url it had to establish a new TCP connection for each and every new request.

Now my question is, if we have persistent connections in http/1.1 then as mentioned above a client does not need to make a new connection for every new request. It can send multiple requests over the same connection. So if the server knows that every subsequent request is coming over the same connection, would it not be obvious that the request is from the same client? And hence would this just not suffice to maintain the state and would this just nit be enough for the server to understand that the request was from the same client ? In this case then why is a separate state management mechanism required at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, yes, it would make sense, but HTTP persistent connections are used to eliminate administrative TCP/IP overhead of connection handling (e.g. connect/disconnect/reconnect, etc.). It is not meant to say anything about the state of the data moving across the connection, which is what you're talking about.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the reply.I understand the your point.But actually that it self was my question, "why can't it be meant to say about the state of the data moving across the connection?" Look if the data is being sent over the same connection it obviously means that it is being sent by the same client that actually opened the conn. So now for every subsequent request (over the same conn) it is known that the request is from the same client. And if i am not wrong it was for this reason that we actually needed to have separate state management mechanisms and that http is a stateless protocol.

Comment: Well, how is a client going to inform the host that new data is being sent? HTTP isn't a streaming data protocol, it's connection-based. So by definition each connection (even if it's purely a logical connection over a persistent physical one) needs to have a beginning with a header, a body, and an end. I see where you're going with this, and by all means, roll your own protocol that does it. But as it stands now, there isn't much overhead already in the system, which is why people don't use anything else: Because this way works just fine.

Comment: Thanks it makes a much better sense now. I'll have to work over it from hereon now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

No. For instance, there might an intermediate (such as a proxy or a reverse proxy) in the request path that aggregates requests from multiple TCP connections.

See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-21.html#intermediaries.

Comment: could you please elaborate a little .. may be with an example.