# Maintaining session state across two http different requests in an application

Tags: java, rest, session, servlets, cookies

I have a scenario where I want to store session information across multiple sessions in Application # 2. We have two applications deployed on a tomcat server. Our use case is as follows:

A. Web Application # 1 makes a HTTP Post request to Application # 2 using a HTTP Rest  Client. POST request contains a JSON http request body encapsulating the data to be send to Application # 2. The code block is as follows:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
final SearchCustomer customer = new SearchCustomer();
restTemplate.execute(
    SEND_CUSTOMER_PROFILE, HttpMethod.POST,
    new SearchRequestCallback(searchCustomer), null);
```

The request callback function is

```
static class SearchRequestCallback implements RequestCallback {


  /**
   * Write a JSON response to the request body.
   */
    @Override
    public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
      HttpHeaders httpHeaders = request.getHeaders();
      List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new LinkedList<>();
      acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      httpHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
      httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
      request.getBody().write(
          new Gson().toJson(this.searchCustomer).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName()));
    }
  }
```

The second application has a Spring controller with the following set up

```
@Controller
public class SearchCustomerController {

  /**
   * Builds customer profile knowledge graph.
   * 
   * <p>This is invoked as an synchronous request.
   */
  @RequestMapping(value="/searchProfilePayload.go", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public void constructSearchCustomerProfileKnowledgeGraph(
      @RequestBody final SearchCustomer customer, HttpServletRequest request) {
    UserContext userContext =
        (UserContext) request.getSession().getAttribute("userContext");
    if (userContext == null) {
      // Perform heavy operation to fetch user session.
      userContext = UserContextHelper.getUserContext(request);
      request.getSession("userContext", userContext)
    }
    userContext.setCustomerProfile(customer);
  }
}
```

When I make a call to another URI within the application # 2 say via browser, I want it done in such as way that the session attributes are retained when making this call. Is there a way to do that?

I know about [URL rewriting](http://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-servlet-session-management-tutorial-with-examples-of-cookies-httpsession-and-url-rewriting#servlet-url-rewriting) that stores `JSESSIONID`in the cookie, but I don't think how you can set the value when making a rest call, and using the same `JESSIONID` to maintain session attributes.

Is there a better way to do this? These have no answers. I have looked at these links, but none seem to answer my question.

[HTTP and Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965701/http-and-sessions)
[comparison of ways to maintain state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95655/comparison-of-ways-to-maintain-state)

Comment: Not sure if this is of help at all, but maybe it will be.  Sending cookies with RestTemplate: http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/08/sending-cookies-with-resttemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jraahhali is spot on.

Set the cookie header with the value of JSESSIONID=${sessionId} or use it directly in the url as per the URL rewriting link.

First step is to retrieve the JSESSIONID from the initial response (this will depend on how you decide to set the session id - URL or Cookies, lets assume by cookie for now)

```
@Override
public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
  HttpHeaders httpHeaders = request.getHeaders();
  List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new LinkedList<>();
  acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  httpHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
  httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  request.getBody().write(
      new Gson().toJson(this.searchCustomer).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName()));

  ClientHttpResponse response = request.execute();
  String sessionId = response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE).split(":")[1].trim(); // I didnt test this, will prolly get a NPE :P
  this.sessionId = sessionId;
}
```

Then in subsequent requests (ie from the app #1 or a browser or whatever)

```
if (this.sessionId != null && !this.sessionId.equals(""))
  httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, "JSESSIONID=" + this.sessionId);

// ...
request.execute();
```

Note if you really want to use a browser as the other client then I would use the URL rewriting method for ease of use ...

Comment: How would I be able to use URL Rewriting if the cookies are generated programatically? How do I set the cookie up in the browser?

Comment: the point of URL Rewriting is that the session id is on the URL as a query string parameter. It doesn't use cookies, so it's easy to share the session across browsers, applications and so on.

Comment: I see. I think I have got it. Thanks. I made a slight modification to your suggested solution. Spring's RestTemplate exposes a ResponseExtractor to extract the response you want. I extracted the session id as follows

@Override
    public String extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
      String sessionId = response.getHeaders().getFirst("Set-Cookie");
      Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(sessionId);
       while (m.find()) {
         return m.group(1);
      }
      return null;
    }